# Ejs renders {} when including partials

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) as reference to build a simple `ejs` app.
Project structure:
- views
----- partials
---------- head.ejs
----- pages
---------- index.ejs
- package.json
- server.js

server.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
app  = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/index');
});
```

head.ejs :

```
<title>My Awesome Site</title>
```

index.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head.ejs %> <!-- commenting out this line works -->
</head>
<body class="container">

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center header">
        <a href="http://www.myawesomesite.org"><img src="/images/phbc_17.jpg"></a>
        <h2 class="page-header">Be Awesome!</h2>
        <p>Visit <a href="http://www.myawesomesite.org">www.myawesomesite.org</a></p>
    </div>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Index renders as expected when I am not including `head.ejs` partial in it. But, with `head.ejs` it's rendering only `{}` in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw two problems.

1. You didn't import `ejs`in your `server.ejs` file so import is as

   ```
   const ejs = require('ejs');
   ```
2. Your `ejs` syntax is a mistake so use below syntax

   ```
   <%- include ('../partials/head.ejs'); %>
   ```

   and this need to be inside your `body` tag

Comment: I only used point 2 and it worked for me. Probably the tutorial was working with older version of ejs, it was published on 2014.